# Read & save the value of a specific cell of a CSV file in a variable using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a csv file namely `ng.csv` where `ID,Envr,Domain,Rule Label,Output` are the column headers & my first row values are

```
CC,     Dev,    AD,     Regular account (user logon),   CC05
```

I have successfully imported the csv file `ng.csv` & read it into the variable `$data` using the below command -

```
$data = import-csv "C:\Users\aghosh\Desktop\ng.csv" -header("ID","Envr","Domain","Rule Label","Output")
```

Now I want to read & save the value `CC05` (ie.row1 x column5) in a variable using Powershell 2.0 commandlets. Can you please help with the same?

Comment: I tried - $data | where-object $_."Rule Label" -eq "Regular service account (user logon)". But I had problem in reading the column "Rule Label" as it had spaces.So, i could not reach to my desired cell.

Comment: Now I'm confused about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to select a single piece of data, or all objects where the Label property is equal to "Regular service account (user logon)"?

Comment: I want to select a single piece of data "CC05" (ie.row1 x column5). But my first try was the above, which failed. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space made no difference for me. Looks like you forgot brackets:

`$data | where-object {$_."Rule Label" -eq "Regular service account}`

Comment: I would like to use the "where-object" filter. Something like -     $data | where-object $_."Rule Label" -eq "Regular service account (user logon)".

Comment: Yup that helped. I missed the brackets. Can you please help me get to my specific cell (row1 x column5). I am not able to get through with the "Label" option.

Comment: `$data[0]."Rule Label"` I misread and thought it was simply Label.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could fetch my desired cell data in a variable. Hey, would you know how to free up my objects eg. $data once I am done.